# Create post request to add user to group using Microsoft graph Java Sdk

Tags: java, sdk, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to add user to a group in outlook using micorosoft graph API in java. I've referred to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/group_post_members
for adding user.

However to achieve this I'm using *microsoft graph java sdk* and I need to add the *json* object with member *Id* in the group in java.

Please let me know how I can add the json object  in the body of the request in java.

My code looks as below:

```
    public void addMemberToGroup(String groupId,String userId) 
{
    final List<Option> options = new LinkedList<Option>();
    Group group =  mGraphServiceClient
                                      .groups(groupId)
                                      .buildRequest()
                                      .get();

    mGraphServiceClient
                        .groups(groupId)
                        .members(userId)
                        .buildRequest()
                        .post(group, 
                               /*add json in body*/
                              );
```

Please let me know how I can add data in body as given below

```
    {
      "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a high level.

```
            // ============================================================
        // Create Service Principal

        ServicePrincipal servicePrincipal = authenticated.servicePrincipals().define(servicePrincipalName)
                .withNewApplication("http://" + servicePrincipalName)
                .create();
        // wait till service principal created and propagated
        SdkContext.sleep(15000);
        System.out.println("Created Service Principal:");
        Utils.print(servicePrincipal);
        spId = servicePrincipal.id();

        // ============================================================
        // Assign role to Service Principal

        RoleAssignment roleAssignment2 = authenticated.roleAssignments()
                .define(raName2)
                .forServicePrincipal(servicePrincipal)
                .withBuiltInRole(BuiltInRole.CONTRIBUTOR)
                .withSubscriptionScope(defaultSubscription)
                .create();
        System.out.println("Created Role Assignment:");
        Utils.print(roleAssignment2);

        // ============================================================
        // Create Active Directory groups

        System.out.println("Creating Active Directory group " + groupName1 + "...");
        ActiveDirectoryGroup group1 = authenticated.activeDirectoryGroups()
                .define(groupName1)
                .withEmailAlias(groupEmail1)
                .create();

        System.out.println("Created Active Directory group " + groupName1);
        Utils.print(group1);

        System.out.println("Creating Active Directory group " + groupName2 + "...");
        ActiveDirectoryGroup group2 = authenticated.activeDirectoryGroups()
                .define(groupName2)
                .withEmailAlias(groupEmail2)
                .create();

        System.out.println("Created Active Directory group " + groupName2);
        Utils.print(group2);

        System.out.println("Adding group members to group " + groupName2 + "...");
        group2.update()
                .withMember(user)
                .withMember(servicePrincipal)
                .withMember(group1)
                .apply();
        System.out.println("Group members added to group " + groupName2);
        Utils.print(group2);
```